# Visual Studio - External Tools not visible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, external-tools

I have a co worker who is trying to add WCF Test Client to the Tools Menu in Visual Studio.

She adds the tools in just fine (exactly the same as mine that are working) but the tools listed in external tools are not visible in the Tools Menu.

I seem to remember there is an option to make these show up in this list, but I don't know where it is.

Anyone out there know this one?

---

Since I did not believe my coworker until she showed me, here are some screen shots in case you don't believe me.

External Tools Window:

[External Tools http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/9438/externaltools.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/9438/externaltools.png)

But even with all that filled in this is all that is in the Tools Menu:

[Tools Menu http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/313/toolsmenu.png](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/313/toolsmenu.png)

Answer (score 21):

Try this:
Go to Tools > Customize.
On the Commands tab, select Tools from the menu bar drop down.
Select an item from the Controls list near where you want to add the command. 
Then click the Add Command button.
In the Add Command dialog, select the Tools category. 
From the Commands list, select External Command X.
Click Ok. 
The external command should now show up under your Tools menu.

Comment: Daniel is correct. Thanks for the good answer. Looks like MS thoughtfully hides the first 5 external tools you might try to add.

Comment: Following Daniel's guide, I was able to see that External Command 4+5 are missing from my VS 2012, so I just added placeholders there and will avoid those slots.

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same problem. My fix was to add dummy commands (cmd.exe) and rearrange the items in the dialog until all my tools showed up in the menu.

In my case, I needed two commands inbetween the others, but I could not figure out which ones were going to be displayed and why.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> external tools -> Add

1. change title to : WCFTestClient
2. Command to : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
3. Initial directory : $(TargetDir)

this is what you get :

[alt text http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/491/54885819.jpg](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/491/54885819.jpg)

Comment: You should find them under the Tools menu

Comment: Yeah, that is the weird part.  They are not there.  (I will try to upload some screen shots.)

Answer (score 0):

Even in my VS 2010 I had to add dummy commands, 6th item shows up!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools>Extensions and Updates...
Pop up will open with all add-on's find your extension and enable it if this is disable.
you may uninstall it from there and install it again as well.
[image]

Then : 
[image]